# window.document sometimes comes out undefined in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, domdocument

Javascript code below works fine in IE8 and older. It simply creates pop-up window with **someHTML** .

```
print_window = window.open('', 'Blah', 'width=500,height=200,left=300,top=300');
doc = print_window.document;
doc.write(someHTML);
self.Window = print_window;
doc.close();
```

In IE10 this code sometimes leaves doc variable 'undefined' generating Javascript error on doc.write(). Interesting that when you are on the page first time it always works for subsequent times it may or may not work.
Can anyone advise on cause and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

@jfriend00 Please try simple code below and on second, third or fourth button click you'll get blank window because window.document is undefined. I'm running IE 10.0.9200.17377.

```
function OpenNew() {
    print_window = window.open('', 'Blah','width=500,height=200,left=300,top=300');
    doc = print_window.document;
    str = '<html><body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" text="#000000">New Window</body></html>';
    doc.write(str);
    self.Window = print_window;
    doc.close();
}

   <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="OpenNew()"/>
```

Comment: I tried, but cannot reproduce this issue in any version of IE.

Comment: Does open() the document help? `doc.open(); doc.write(str);`

Comment: But the window itself appears every time and just the `print_window.document` is `undefined`?

Comment: @epascarello no, any reference to doc returns an error

Comment: @t.niese the window pops up every time, but sometimes document gets undefined and the window stays blank.